# Meaning in pancasila benefit

Tags: sila

I am a Buddhist from Thailand. I have a question about pali meaning.
In ceremony, we swore to follow the five rules of pancasila. Monk told us what pancasila consist of. Then monk said in pali;

Imani panca sikha patani.

Silana sukating yanti

Silana poka sumpata

Silana nipputing yanti

Tusama silang wiso ta ye

I'm not quit sure whether I translate the above to English word correctly. Do you have this chants in your country? What are these chants called? Any reference to this chant? How to spell it in English and what is the meaning of it.

I already searched in Thai language but I want to expand to English as well. It's quit hard to write Pali in English.
Here is the meaning I found in Thai.

As you follow these five rules, you will have good place to go(next life). You will become wealthy. And you may go to nirvana.

I want to compare its meaning from many source especially "ni-pu-ting" in last sentence that referred to nirvana. I don't quit agree that it is the same thing.

Comment: "Do you have this chants in your country?": I'm from Sri Lanka and these chants are not used.

Comment: @Sampath, Thank, maybe not all theravada  has this chant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I want to compare its meaning from many source especially "ni-pu-ting" in last sentence that referred to nirvana.**

Another translation [here](https://thailand.yinteing.com/buddhism/8-precepts/)

> Sīlena nibbutiṁ yanti.
> Through virtue they go to Liberation.
> 因持戒故，使你达证涅盘

I think it's these words -- [nibbuta](https://suttacentral.net/define/nibbuta) and [nibbuti](https://suttacentral.net/define/Nibbuti)

Answer (score 2):

[This chant is a different but has some overlap](https://upavana.org/three-refuges-and-eight-precepts/)

"Sīlena sugatiṃ yanti,

Sīlena bhoga‧sampadā,

Sīlena nibbutiṃ yanti,

Tasmā sīlaṃ visodhaye."

and the English

" Sīla is the way to a good life,

Sīla is the source of true wealth,

Sīla leads to true peace,

Therefore, let Sīla be pure!"